# Netmera Android SDK Pagination

Tags: android, pagination, netmera

What is the purpose of setPage() function of NetmeraService in [Netmera Android SDK](http://netmera.com)? For example, when we search as setPage(3) and setMax(10), is it creating a query for 30 results and respond as pages of 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setPage()` and `setMax()` methods are used to make pagination during the search, but they are not used as you describe.

`setMax()` method is used to define total number of results returned from the search. Default value of `setMax()` is 10.  For example, if you set `setMax(15)` then 15 result will be returned as a search result in each call.

`setPage()` is used to  retrive the contents of the given page. Default value of `setPage()` is 0 . if you set `setPage(1)` then it will skip `page*max` content and retrieve the other `max` content.

For example,  if you set `setPage(1)` and `setMax(20)` then, it will skip 1*20 contents and retrieve the contents between 21-41.